# Salesforce / Salesforcesos SSL certificate expired causing Android build fails

Tags: ssl

On the site where the Salesforce's Chat UI `pom` file is hosted ([here](https://salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/3.0.0/chat-ui-3.0.0.pom)) the SSL certificate just expired, making the builds fail with the following error:

```
Could not resolve com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:3.0.0.
```

Required by:
      project :app > project :react-native-salesforce-chat

> Could not resolve com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:3.0.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/3.0.0/chat-ui-3.0.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/3.0.0/chat-ui-3.0.0.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed

[image]

Could you tell me if there is any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have in their documentation:

NOTE: The certificate for the server used for our original Snap-ins SDK repository just expired. We've changed the location of our repository. Workaround: Replace the salesforcesos.com maven repository in your gradle scripts to

https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android/releases